# How to put Java classes and xml file (used with Hibernate) in Tomcat then call it with an HTTP request?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, http, tomcat

I have a Java class that inserts data in an Oracle database, using Hibernate. I work on Eclipse.

I would want to export all that code to a Tomcat server. In that code, I have Java classes and a hibernate.cfg.xml file to handle mapping with Oracle database.

**Then, my ultimate goal is to call that code through an HTTP request :**

1 ) I launch the HTTP request

2 ) Data insertion is done (because the Java code located in Tomcat would have been called).

**My question is** : how can I export all my code in tomcat : java classes + hibernate.cfg.xml file + libraries (ojdb6.jar...) ?

And, should I put the classes as they are already or modify them to include some `doGet` and `doPost`methods ? Knowing that I do not intend to print anything on the page, just launch the data insertion.

Comment: You just clean your project and create war file of your project. Then place the war file in your webapps folder of tomcat and then start the tomcat server

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm going to try that and let you know if it works.

Comment: In eclipse, right-click on project, go in maven --> clean and then again go there, click on install. In your home directory, there is a .m2 folder, there with the project name specified in POM.xml, you will find the .war file. Copy it in your tomcats webapps folder, now if you want the context path to be root i.e / , then rename the war file to ROOT.war. Start tomcat, enjoy. Lemme know if you need help.

Comment: Ok, @We are Borg, I will let you know, thanks